# Liftings in Covering Map Closed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $p:\tilde{X} \mapsto X$ be a covering map with $\tilde{X}$ path connected.  Why are all liftings of a closed path $f$ in $X$ either closed or not closed?  If $\omega$ is a path from $\tilde{x_0}$ to $\tilde{x_1}$, both in the pre-image of $x_0$ in $X$, $p\omega$ will be a closed path based at $x_0$ in $X$.  The path homo
topy lifting theorem then guarantees that all liftings of $p\omega$ starting at $\tilde{x_0}$ equal $\omega$.  But why can't there be another closed lift based at another point in the pre-image of $x_0$?

Edit:  $p$ is a regular covering

Comment: You can show that if you take a path $\gamma$ from a point $x_{0}$ to $x_{1}$ in the base, then for a fixed preimage $\tilde{x}_{0}$ of $x_{0}$, there is a unique lift of $\gamma$ that starts at $\tilde{x}_{0}.$ The idea is to cover the path with finitely many open sets on which the covering is locally trivial.

Comment: Could you expand a bit?  I don't quite understand how one can produce a finite open covering and what you mean by "locally trivial."

Comment: I'm sorry. I misread your question as why are lifts of paths unique. I'm not sure that it is actually true that in any covering space, lifts of closed paths are closed or not closed independent of choice of preimage of the base point. This fact is definitely true in normal covering spaces i.e. covering spaces in which there is a transitive action on the pre-images of the base point by deck transformations because then, finding the lift at a different base point is obtained by acting by a deck transformation. In the absence of normality, I am not sure.

Comment: Also, normal covering spaces are classified as those whose fundamental groups are normal subgroups of $\pi_{1}(X)$. In particular, the universal cover is normal.

Comment: @Siddarth Venkatesh Sorry - I've edited the question.

Comment: @Siddarth Venkatesh Again, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Aren't all paths either closed or not closed?

Comment: Dear @Joe Johnson, Maybe Barry means that, either every lift (i.e. as the point in the fiber over the base point varies) of $f$ is closed, or none of them are.

Comment: Are you aware of the basic example of covering $\Bbb R\to S^1$? The constant path is lifted to a constant path (hence, closed), but the full circle on $S^1$ lifts to a segment in this covering.

Comment: Yes I am aware, but this is not a counterexample.

Comment: Can someone resolve this?  Is the problem statement incorrect, or am I missing something?

Comment: I should probably add that the definition of regular that I am working with is that there exists $\tilde{x}_0 \in \tilde{X}$ such that $p_{*} \pi(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi(X,x_0)$.

Comment: Ok. I'll elaborate in an answer. I can also point you to a resource: Hatcher's Algebraic Topology page 70-71.

Answer (score 2):

In a regular covering, the group of deck transformations acts transitively on the fiber of any chosen point. See Hatcher's Algebraic Topology page 70-71 (he calls regular coverings, normal.)

So, suppose we have a loop $\gamma$ in $X$ with $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = x$. Let us take two different lifts $\gamma', \gamma''$ using two different points $x', x''$ in $p^{-1}(x)$. By the first statement, there is a deck transformation $F : \tilde{X} \rightarrow \tilde{X}$ that takes $x'$ to $x''$. Now, we have
$$p \circ F \circ \gamma' = p \circ \gamma' = \gamma$$
because $p \circ F = p$ by definition of deck transformation. Hence $F \circ \gamma'$ is a path that lifts $\gamma$ and is based on $x''.$ By uniqueness of lifts of paths, $\gamma'' = F \circ \gamma'.$

Now, it is clear from the above argument that $\gamma''(0) = F(\gamma'(0))$ and $\gamma''(1) = F(\gamma'(1))$. Since $F$ is a homeomorphism and hence a bijection, we see that $\gamma'$ is a loop if and only if $\gamma''$ is a loop.

Comment: I would rather see a proof which directly uses the definition of regularity I gave above.

Comment: Hatcher proves that your definition is equivalent to the transitive action of the group of desk transformations. That was the proof I cited.